# wrong result when std::for_each is called in a template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang++

test code:

```
template<typename T>
void test() {
    T container { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), [](int v) {
        cout<<"1st for_each"<<endl; 
    });

    cout<<"xxxxxx"<<endl;
    std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), [](typename T::value_type v) { 
        cout<<"2nd for_each"<<endl;
    });
}


int main() {
    test<vector<int>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that i use `int i` and `typename T::value_type v` param types in different lambdas.
compile cmd: `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -o test`

clang version 3.1 (branches/release_31)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

result:

```
2nd for_each  
2nd for_each  
2nd for_each  
xxxxxx  
2nd for_each  
2nd for_each  
2nd for_each
```

The problem is: why first `for_each` print out "2nd for_each"?

Edit: It may a clang++ bug.
@KennyTM gave a similar simpler code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
void test() {
    ([](int v) { printf("1\n"); })(3); 
    ([](T v) { printf("2\n"); })(4);
}

int main() { 
    test<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

result:
1
1

Comment: This is quite odd. You may have actually found a compiler bug.

Comment: Are you sure you are running an executable built from the code you posted?

Comment: Even curiouser, capturing the `container` by-value in the second lambda causes an infinite loop. Doing so in the first also causes an infinite loop, but that eventually terminates in a crash (I assume stack overflow but I didn't check).

Comment: @juanchopanza: I can reproduce on my machine

Comment: gcc works correctly: http://liveworkspace.org/code/d591d2f5225c2c22ea726313395fb5d7

Comment: I've filed a bug report with Apple with this code.

Comment: Simpler test case: `template<typename T> void test() { ([](int v) { printf("1\n"); })(3); ([](T v) { printf("2\n"); })(4); } int main() { test<int>(); }` (Both prints '1'.)

Comment: sure sounds like a bug. probably the compiler's name mangling is resulting in the names for the two lambdas being the same, and so one is getting wiped out.

Comment: @tletnes: That appears to be exactly what's happening. If you print the typeids of those lambdas they're identical.

Comment: I've filed a bug report on the Clang Bugzilla, here: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13849  It links to the rdar:// filed earlier by Kevin (which is visible only to people on Apple's internal network).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was a Clang bug, and was fixed by [r160614](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20120716/061195.html). Clang trunk gives the desired output:

```
$ echo '
#include <cstdio>
template<typename T>
void test() {
    ([](int) { puts("int"); })(0);
    ([](double) { puts("double"); })(0);
    ([](T) { puts("T"); })(0);
}

int main() { test<int>(); test<double>(); }
' | ./build/bin/clang -x c++ -std=c++11 -
$ ./a.out
int
double
T
int
double
T
```

See [PR12917](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12917) and [PR13849](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13849) for more information.